# C# LINQ GroupBy error: variable {name} of type > {type} > referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am writing a Linq query that will be applied to an SQL DB.
This is the query:

```
var entitiesGroups = await _context.ProductsDetailsStatisticsView
        .GroupBy(p => p.Id, (productDetailsId, info) => new
        {
            Key = productDetailsId,
            Info = info
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

I am getting the following error when this query is evaluated:

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'info' of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProductDetailsStatisticsEntity]'
> referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Since you need all records, do grouping on the client side:

```cs
var entitiesGroups = (await _context.ProductsDetailsStatisticsView.ToListAsync())
    .GroupBy(p => p.Id, (productDetailsId, info) => new
    {
        Key = productDetailsId,
        Info = info
    })
    .ToList();
```